# Slow Code Trying to get 7zip Password

Tags: python, python-3.x

Like many before me I've lost my 7zip password. Actually it was destroyed along with everything else in my previous cell phone.  I'm 99% sure I know most of the password so I'm assuming it will be tractable to brute force crack it so I wrote the code shown and it works but is horrifically slow.  21 attempts in 6.1 seconds to get the example.   The bottleneck is clearly the sp.wait() but everything I've tried to get around that won't work.  I guess it makes sense since Python can't know anything about the process till its done.  I tried many variations of try/except on the subprocess.Popen() to no avail.  Note that 7zip will place a 0KB version of the file in the folder with the wrong password but the folder has to be empty when the right password is used to not generate a different error.  Fictional password in the code.  Working on Win 7 in Python 3.5.1 with 7zip v9.2.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks, Joe.

```
import os
import time
import itertools
import subprocess

start_time = time.time()
cmdline = r"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z e C:\archive.7z -oC:\temp -p"
path = r"C:\temp"

unknown_part='$oz'
known_part='MiStup!dB'
attempts = 0

for password_length in range(2, 4):
    for guess in itertools.product(unknown_part, repeat=password_length):
        try:
            os.remove(r'C:\temp\extractedfile.txt')
        except:
            None
        attempts += 1
        guess = ''.join(guess)
        newline = cmdline + known_part + guess
        sp = subprocess.Popen(newline, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        sp.wait()
        if sp.returncode == 0:
            print("Password is %s, Found in %i attempts in %s seconds" % (known_part+guess, attempts, time.time()-start_time))
            break
```

Comment: Have you tried using a Python module/package instead of using the 7z command line tool through a subprocess?

Comment: Working through a known range like this is likely to be [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) and would massively benefit from parallelised.

Comment: StefanPochmann, No, reading up on libarchive now.  Looks viable, I'll work at it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @StefanPochmann, I could not find how to add a password to libarchive, and Lzma is not 7zip compatible. Is there another package you know of?

Comment: @match, added a ThreadPool() and got it down to 2.9 seconds on a dual quad core system,  How many threads can I add or is this just trial and error till the machine freezes?

Comment: Wow! ThreadPool() isn't linear and just did 3750 attempts on a password length twice as long in 50 seconds! Only issue now is I need to figure out how to stop it after it gets the right password.  I feel I have a tractable solution now thanks.